MongoDB Aggregation Not Working On Encrypted Field
I have a MongoDB collection using Client-Side Field Level Encryption. It has a field called uid encrypted using the AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_512-Deterministic algorithm. In the Atlas web UI, I'm using this aggregation pipeline but it's not outputting any records even though I have records with uid field set to system_user.
MongoDB docs say that the $match aggregation stage is supported for CSFLE. What am I getting wrong?
[
  {
    $match: {
      "uid": "system_user"
    }
  }
]

My CSFLE encryption schema for the collection:
{
    "$jsonSchema": {
        "bsonType": "object",
        "title": "Account",
        "properties": {
            "uid": {
                "encrypt": {
                    "bsonType": "string",
                    "algorithm": "AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_512-Deterministic",
                    "keyId": [<dek>]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


How are you providing the master key to the Atlas web UI?

@Joe Where do I provide the master key? I can't find it in the Atlas web UI

I don't know if there is one, which is why I asked.  The whole point of encryption is you can't read the data without the key, so if there is no way to provide the key, you won't be able to query the encrypted field.

@Joe using CSFLE and the MDB node.js driver, it would be in the validator and autoEncryption schemaMap option, right?
